# How to reset passwords in Nautilus, Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, nautilus

I had a user connect to a remote server (via `nautilus`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, `smb://url`).
Was prompted for a password like this, and I said "remember forever". Now I have got a new user with extended permissions which I need, but my old user is still active on their system, so `nautilus` doesn't prompt for the new password (which I need to change user). How can I reset the password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password manager for GNOME Keyring is **`seahorse`** (which should show up as "Passwords and Encryption Keys" in your program list).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Click on the Dash home → Password and Keys → Choose the FTP password to delete.